# Outlier in three dimension

Tags: outliers

I am looking for an example of an outlier in three dimensions but that cannot be detected with the three scatters xy, xz, yz. Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be a point inside a ball?

Comment: there should be some examples here: https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/baileyj/papers/DMKD_final16.pdf Another example would be if there are multiple clusters (balls) and you have a point somewhere in the centre that is far from all.

Comment: Occultation on a finite mixture model. I’m thinking 3x3x3 lattice of point clouds, but without actual center cloud. Any point there appears to be member of other cluster, but isn’t. Remove components at cube corners for increased simplicity.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Simone, thanks for your comment and references. Augusto.

Comment: It comes down to what you mean by "outlier" as well as what you would consider to be an "example."  Would an example be a real dataset or a synthetic one?  How do you propose to assess or quantify "outliers," whatever they might be?